# Linux grep stop at first match any of this chars: " ' # whitespace

Tags: regex, grep

I want to get a string that matches a Perl regex until one of this characters appear: `" , ' , whitespace , #`

While this works for `whitespace` and `"`

```
grep -Poi 'form.*?action=["\s]?\K.*?(?="\s)' file.php
```

I can't make it work for `#` and `'`. I have tried this but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
  grep -Poi 'form.*?action=["\s]?\K.*?(?="\s#\')' file.php
```

Comment: You probably meant `(?=["\s#\'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell syntax doesn't support escaping inside single-quoted strings. Switch to a double-quoted string for that part of the argument.

```
grep -Poi 'form.*?action=["\s]?\K.*?(?="\s#'"')" file.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have a problem, now the bash doesn't show an error but the grep command doesn't provide me the string that matches the Perl regex until one of those characters appears. Instead if I write (?=["\s#\']) it works. Do you know why?

Comment: If you want to match a single character that's one of a set, you need to put it in `[ ... ]`. Without the brackets, it's matching a string of characters, not a set.

Comment: `\s#'` matches a space followed by `#` followed by `'`. `[\s#']` matches a space, `#` or `'`.